# Python Bencoding using BitTorrent-bencode 5.0.8.1

Tags: python

I'm new to python and bencoding. I need to read and write torrent files for my project using python. I have already imported the module and here's my code to parse the torrent:

Here's the link to my module http://paste2.org/p/1442120 which is a mod of http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitTorrent-bencode/5.0.8.1

```
            import sys
            from bencode import *
            f = open('file.torrent','rb') #binary read write
            for line in f:
                    print line, 
                    print bdecode(line)
```

This throws invalid bencoded string error
If I understand correctly, the bdecode function needs one value at a time but how do I parse the torrent file? or ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that Bencoded files are not line oriented files.  What you're doing is like taking a report, putting it through the shredder, and handing it to your boss one shred at a time.  Here is the correct way to decode a Bencoded file:

```
import bencode
print bencode.bdecode(open('file.torrent', 'rb').read())
```

Comment: That works just fine. Thanks. So this is passing a buffer to the bdecode function right?

Comment: I haven't used 2.x in ages, but in 3.x we call it a `bytes` object.